# Django finding the field name containing a string

Tags: django

I have 2 software platforms with identical documents on them but different filenames. If I have an instance of 1 filename, I want to get the corresponding filename from the other platform.

In my example below fields suffixed with a would store filenames for one platform and those suffixed with b store the corresponding filename from the other platform

So if I have a list:

```
 my_list=['fname', 'anotherfname', 'andanotherfn']
```

My Model includes:

```
class DocumentIndex(models.Model):
    Carfilenamea = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Carfilenameb = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Housefilenamea = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Housefilenameb = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Vanfilenamea = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    Vanfilenameb = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
    ...
```

Each item in my list will only be in the database once.

If 'fname' was stored in Housefilenamea I want to get the data from Housefilenameb

Comment: search the model or search the Database?

Comment: You need to clarify the workflow desired, ideally with examples and (pseudo)code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b_list = []
for fname in my_list:
    try:
        instance = DocumentIndex.objects.get(housefilenamea=fname)
        b_list.append(instance.housefilenameb)
    except DocumentIndex.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```